# Making icons for a Google Play Store game

Tags: unreal-4, publishing, google-play

I'm a little confused.

I've created a game using the Unreal Engine and I plan to publish in about a month. I knew my app needed an icon, but I was on Google's developer site yesterday and I saw a whole BUNCH of guidelines for icons, and there are several kinds. They say something about placing different versions of the icon in my 'resources' directory, but I didn't develop in Android Studio. I thought I would just be making one 512x512 icon, and uploading my APK (plus the other info).

Could someone who has used Unreal and published to the Play Store please help me :) Do I really have to make so many icons?

Comment: You should probably update your question's title to focus on your actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Android will always pick the best match being available.

The basic idea is to provide multiple sizes of your icon (and other resources) so the device can pick the best fit without having to downscale (or visually worse: upscale) everything all the time.

Just remember a bigger icon will take more resources and scaling might not always result in the image quality you want.

Comment: Alright, thanks for answering :) and I approved your suggested edit. So if I wanted to provide multiple sizes, would I HAVE to use Android Studio, or will Google prompt me to provide icons when publishing? If I had to use Android Studio, do you know how I would "attach" my APK? Sorry these might sound basic.. I'm a n00b

Comment: @Bowserjr. The icons have to be included in your APK. It doesn't matter which IDE (if any) your using. I haven't used UE4 with Android, so no idea about the actual workflow.

Comment: Lol, I actually just discovered that UE4 does in fact have it's own XML directories, so you're right. Thanks a lot for clearing things up bro!